# How to number a columns name pandas

Tags: python, list, pandas, dataframe

I want to name columns in a pandas dataframe from 1 to length of the data.

I have

```
foo = pd.DataFrame(n, columns=('protein', 1...n ))
```

Comment: What is 'protein' here? Do you want the first column to be named protein and the rest from 1 to n?

Comment: i can del this :) it might be column with number 0. First column is the names of proteins. Second and foreward is position in sequence from 1 to n :)

Comment: 1 to len(data)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default column names in pandas is 0 to range(len(data))-1. So if you don't pass the columns = parameter in pd.DataFrame and then rename first column, you will get desired result

Eg:
    n = np.ones(10).reshape(2,5)
    df = pd.DataFrame(n)

```
    0   1   2   3   4
0   1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0
1   1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0
```

Now

```
df = df.rename(columns = {0: 'protein'})

    protein 1   2   3   4
0   1.0     1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0
1   1.0     1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0
```